# No main classes found with github project

Tags: java, github

I have downloaded a Java project from github and tried to use it in NetBeans but when I want to test the project by running it it said "No main classes found". This is the project I downloaded [sumo report generator](https://github.com/SumoLogic/sumo-report-generator/).

Comment: Did you import it as a Maven project? There is a main class at https://github.com/SumoLogic/sumo-report-generator/blob/master/src/main/java/com/sumologic/commandline/SumoReportCommandLine.java

Comment: and how do you test it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find the main method in the following class.

**SumoReportCommandLine.java**

https://github.com/SumoLogic/sumo-report-generator/blob/master/src/main/java/com/sumologic/commandline/SumoReportCommandLine.java

Besides, it is a maven project, you have to import as maven project in your favorite IDE.
In maven pom.xml file also, you can also see that the main method class has been mentioned as

> com.sumologic.commandline.SumoReportCommandLine

```
<plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <addDefaultImplementationEntries>true</addDefaultImplementationEntries>
                            <addDefaultSpecificationEntries>true</addDefaultSpecificationEntries>
                            <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                            <classpathPrefix>lib/</classpathPrefix>
                            <mainClass>com.sumologic.commandline.SumoReportCommandLine</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's there.

https://github.com/SumoLogic/sumo-report-generator/blob/master/pom.xml#L271

How did you open the project? basically it's maven projet.